# How to get all data-attributes from inputs into array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a series of inputs that I need to generate an automatic array if the user type, but when I type, it adds multiple elements in the array.

I need the result like that

```
["10", "20", "30", "40", "50"]
```

but it comes this way if i type again

```
["10", "20", "30", "40", "50", "40", "30", "30", "30", "20"]
```

How do I add only once when typing?

```js
const $input = document.querySelectorAll("input")

var items = [];

$input.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('input', () => {

    boxdata = item.getAttribute('data-valor')
    items.push(boxdata);

    console.log(items);
  })
})
```

```html
item 1: <input type="text"  data-valor="10"> 
item 2: <input type="text"  data-valor="20">
item 3: <input type="text"  data-valor="30">
item 4: <input type="text"  data-valor="40">
item 5: <input type="text"  data-valor="50">
```

Comment: Well what happen is that when the value of the input has been change, it will trigger your forEach function.

Comment: a) use a `Set` b) why do you need to generate the array when the user types? It's not like the `data-valor` value changes, is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Set) like this:

```js
const $input = document.querySelectorAll("input")

const items = new Set();

$input.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('input', () => {

    boxdata = item.getAttribute('data-valor')
    items.add(boxdata);

    console.log([...items]);
  })
})
```

```html
item 1: <input type="text" data-valor="10"> 
item 2: <input type="text" data-valor="20"> 
item 3: <input type="text" data-valor="30"> 
item 4: <input type="text" data-valor="40"> 
item 5: <input type="text" data-valor="50">
```